# Constraint produces "This construct causes code to be less generic..."

Tags: f#

I am trying to use a generic with a constraint to allow access to a property of a parameter.  Accessing the property inside the function produces a compile-time warning of "This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'Item has been constrained to be type 'Foo2'."

```ml
namespace Test
type Foo = { Bar:string; NotUsed:string }
type Foo2 = { Bar:string }

module Shared =
    let inline showMeABar (item: ^Item when ^Item : (member Bar : string)) = item.Bar
```

Did I make a syntax mistake or is this not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling the getter is weird. You can do it explicitly like this:

```
let inline showMeABar item =
    (^Item : (member Bar : string) item)
```

Record labels have the weird (but useful) property that their usage with dot-notation is a hint to type inference. Hence the strange error message.

Comment: Note that you can drop the annotation on `item` since it can now be inferred from the call site.

Comment: @kvb Right, thanks! Edited. *I was just about to try if shortening it is allowed. Also added a note on the compiler warning where one would normally expect the indeterminate type error*

Comment: Thank you @Vandroiy.  I haven't seen that member access syntax before.  Do you happen to know of a good reference for using it?

Comment: @ShawnMartin I don't know of anything to recommend. I guess it is a rarely used feature. A web search for static member constraints gives lots of examples though.